# Start new activity or update values in old, which solution is better for for the performance?

Tags: android, xml, performance, class, structure

Hello Stackoverflow'ers,

as my question says, what is more efficient for programming and performance.

A "next" page button which is doing an update(); and updates every textview in the activity. (my current method)

Or a "next" page button which startActivity(itself). itself is the same layout but a new "page" with the same funktions.

Maybe someone is able to make a good example or has a link which explains a propper struckture of an android app. It´s working, but i want to make it professional.

The Button should be able to set:

- text to several textviews
- set Checkboxes checked in a linearLayout if you go back to the last page ( cause the activity is Scrollable)
- safe checked  checkboxes
- don´t interrupt the timer which s running down

Every funktion i want is already there.. but it runs all with the update(); and im not sure if this is a good way to handle recources

My XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@color/Hp_background2"
android:weightSum="100"
>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="10"
        android:weightSum="100"
        >
        <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:textSize="10dp"
        android:id="@+id/pruefungBeendenButton"
        />
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Timer"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="34"
        android:id="@+id/timerTextview"
        />
        <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fortschritt/60"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="33"
        android:id="@+id/fortschrittTextview"
        />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="80">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:weightSum="100">

                 <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/frageTextview"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                    android:text="Frage"
                    android:textSize="18dp" />
                <View
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="2dp"
                    android:background="@color/black" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_subfragen"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp">
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout_antworten"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
                    android:dividerHeight="0dp">

                </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:weightSum="100">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/vorherigeFrage_Button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/beantworten_button"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="60" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/naechsteFrage_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />
</LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

You know, i was in a programmes Highscool but it´s 2 years later now and it seems that i can´t find a recipt for a good structure in android.

MfG Phil

Comment: add a new activity on every button click is a bad idea. An android app and it´s activities is like a stack. Everytime you start a new actiity, it´s on the top of the stack. If you do it like this, you would have in anytime a big stack of activities. To prevent this, you must finish the running activity everytime. If it´s exactly the same layout, just update everything...

Comment: this means an app is like a webseite with these layers? interessting but this was my guess. Is there an article about this? 
Ty for your answer!

Comment: or you can start Activities as single task

Comment: [This?](https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/understand-android-activity-launchmode/en)

Answer (score 0):

Using same activity will reduce the activity creation overhead.Since creating multiple activities will keep them in back stack unless you define them with required launch modes like single task, single top which will re bring the activities from back stack and will redraw them

Comment: Ok, but the timer would run on all 120 question activityes? if it is so wouldn´t this be a decrease in performance? Or is it possible to submit an object of a timer which won´t get interupptet in counting if you open a new/old activity?